# I'm trying to convert an ISO date from an API to alphabetical months, how can you do it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to convert the following date I'm getting from the API:

```
2022-04-01T05:09:09.403Z
```

To the next one:

```
July 19, 2021
```

But I don't know how to do it. I've tried this so far:

```
  const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

for (var i = 0; i < postsResults.length; i++) {
  const trimmedData = postsResults[i].last_posted_at
  const finalData = trimmedData.substring(0, 10);
  let monthDate = finalData.slice(5,7)
  if (monthDate.includes(0)) {
    monthDate = finalData.slice(6,7)
  } else {
    monthDate = finalData.slice(5,7)
  }
  result = months[monthDate]
}
```

Postsresults is the array that I'm fetching. I'm slicing certain characters until I get the exact letters to match the months. This doesn't work as it always returns April.

Comment: Try `new Date('2022-04-01T05:09:09.403Z').toLocaleDateString('en-US', { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'})`

Comment: No but it is an arry of dates, so  it is not always the same date

Comment: Instead of `const trimmedData...` simply do: `result = new Date(postResults[i].last_posted_at).toLocaleDateString([], { month: 'long' });` and remove the rest of the lines in the `for...` loop. Thsi will give you the full-month-name.